# Unity Processing Data Stream from Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

## Background

I have a simple working server which sends binary from a data collection device, the socket connection works and both my Unity client and other clients(like matlab client) can receive the data correctly.

Then a client in Unity trying to receive the data from this server and segment the bytes from each packet into 3D coordinates array.

Each frame should be 512x424 pixels large, so that's why I need to wait until the data fills 512x424 bytes and do the segmentation

## The Problem

Unity runs fine on at the socket connection and receiving stage, it will get stuck(stall) on the processing stage: `ProcessFrame((byte[])state.buffer.Clone())`

I have read this SO post:
[Getting UdpClient Receive data back in the Main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588443/getting-udpclient-receive-data-back-in-the-main-thread?lq=1)
and changed my code accordingly, but the problem persists.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help :)

## Code --- client

> ```
> public class SomeClass: MonoBehaviour {
> public GameObject sphere;
> const int IMGW = 512;
> const int IMGH = 424;
> const int MAXBODY = 6;
> const int NUMJOINT = 25;
> const int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = (4 * 3 + 4 * 1 + 4 * 1) * (IMGW * IMGH + MAXBODY * NUMJOINT);
> const int PORT_NUM = 20156;
> public string response = String.Empty;
> private Queue queue;
> private System.Object queueLock;
> private int bytesRead;
> // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
> private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
>     new ManualResetEvent(false);
> private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
>     new ManualResetEvent(false);
> private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
>     new ManualResetEvent(false);
>
> // State object for receiving data from remote device.
> public class StateObject
> {
>     // Client socket.
>     public Socket workSocket = null;
>     // Receive buffer.
>     public const int BufferSize = (4 * 3 + 4 * 1 + 4 * 1) * (IMGW * IMGH + MAXBODY * NUMJOINT);
>     public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
> }
>
> // We use this to keep tasks needed to run in the main thread
> private static readonly Queue<Action> tasks = new Queue<Action>();
>
> // Use this for initialization
> void Start () {
>     queueLock = new object();
>     queue = new Queue();
>     this.StartClient();
>
>   // Test object      
>   sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
>   sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, -1, 10);     
> }         
>   // Update is called once per frame  
>  void Update () {
>     this.HandleTasks();
> }
>
> void HandleTasks()
> {
>     while (tasks.Count > 0)
>     {
>         Action task = null;
>
>         lock (tasks)
>         {
>             if (tasks.Count > 0)
>             {
>                 task = tasks.Dequeue();
>             }
>         }
>
>         task();
>     }
> }
>
> public void QueueOnMainThread(Action task)
> {
>     lock (tasks)
>     {
>         tasks.Enqueue(task);
>     }
> }
>
> private void StartClient()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
>         IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT_NUM);
>
>         Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
>             SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
>
>         // Connect to the remote endpoint.
>         client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
>         connectDone.WaitOne();
>
>         Receive(client);
>         receiveDone.WaitOne();
>
>         Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
>
>         // Release the socket
>         client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
>         client.Close();
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         Debug.Log(e.ToString());
>     }
> }
>
> private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
>         Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
>
>         // Complete the connection.
>         client.EndConnect(ar);
>
>         // Signal that the connection has been made.
>         connectDone.Set();
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         String error = e.ToString();
>         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
>         fnDisconnect();
>     }
> }
>
> private void Receive(Socket client)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         // Create the state object.
>         StateObject state = new StateObject();
>         state.workSocket = client;
>         bytesRead = 0;
>         // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
>         client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, bytesRead, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
>             new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
>     }
> }
>
> private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
>         // from the asynchronous state object.
>         StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
>         Socket client = state.workSocket;
>
>         // Read data from the remote device.
>         int numOfBytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
>
>         if (numOfBytesRead > 0)
>         {
>             bytesRead += numOfBytesRead;
>             if (bytesRead == StateObject.BufferSize)
>             {
>                 this.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
>                 {
>                     // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
>                     ProcessFrame((byte[])state.buffer.Clone());
>                 });
>
>                 Receive(client);
>             }
>             else {
>                 // Get the rest of the data.
>                 client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, bytesRead, StateObject.BufferSize - bytesRead, 0,
>                     new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             receiveDone.Set();
>         }
>
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
>     }
> }
> ```

Code --- Data Processing

> ```
> private void ProcessFrame(byte[] buffer)
> {
>
>     byte[] bufferCopy = (byte[])buffer.Clone();
>
>     double[,,] XYZArray = new double[IMGH, IMGW, 3];
>     byte[,] DepthArray = new byte[IMGH, IMGW];
>     byte[,,] RGBArray = new byte[IMGH, IMGW, 3];
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < IMGW; i++)
>     {
>         for (int j = 0; j < IMGH; j++)
>         {
>             int index = (i * IMGW + j) * 20;
>             //byte[] arr = {bufferCopy[index], bufferCopy[index + 1], bufferCopy[index + 2], bufferCopy[index + 3] };
>             float v = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bufferCopy, index);
>             if (!float.IsInfinity(v) && !float.IsNaN(v))
>             {
>                 XYZArray[i, j, 0] = v;
>             }
>             //arr = new byte[]{bufferCopy[index + 4], bufferCopy[index + 5], bufferCopy[index + 6], bufferCopy[index + 7] };
>             v = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bufferCopy, index + 4);
>             if (!float.IsInfinity(v) && !float.IsNaN(v))
>             {
>                 XYZArray[i, j, 1] = v;
>             }
>             v = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bufferCopy, index + 8);
>             if (!float.IsInfinity(v) && !float.IsNaN(v))
>             {
>                 XYZArray[i, j, 2] = v;
>             }
>             //                            Debug.Log("for loop called");
>             DepthArray[i, j] = bufferCopy[index + 12];
>             RGBArray[i, j, 2] = bufferCopy[index + 16]; // B
>             RGBArray[i, j, 1] = bufferCopy[index + 17]; // G
>             RGBArray[i, j, 0] = bufferCopy[index + 18]; // R
>         }
>     }
>     this.EnQueue(XYZArray);
> }
>
> private void EnQueue(System.Object obj)
> {
>     lock (queueLock)
>     {
>         queue.Enqueue(obj);
>     }
> }
>
> private bool DeQueue(System.Object outObj)
> {
>     bool success = false;
>     lock (queueLock)
>     {
>         if (queue.Count > 0)
>         {
>             outObj = queue.Dequeue();
>             success = true;
>         }
>     }
>     return success;
> }
>
> public int lengthOfQueue()
> {
>     int count = -1;
>     lock (queueLock)
>     {
>         count = queue.Count;
>     }
>     return count;
> }
>
> public double[,,] getXYZArray()
> {
>     double[,,] retVal = new double[,,] { };
>     this.DeQueue(retVal);
>     return retVal;
> }
> ```

## UPDATE

Thanks for @Programmer 's advice and I followed the link (s)he provided got a working socket client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole code is a mess. You should have used `Thread` instead of `Async` to accomplish that with less code.

Any ways, replace the `byte[] bufferCopy = (byte[])buffer.Clone();` line of code with

```
byte[] bufferCopy = new byte[buffer.Length];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, bufferCopy, 0, bufferCopy.Length);
```

And for `ProcessFrame((byte[])state.buffer.Clone());`, simply pass in the data without cloning it. So that should be replaced with

```
ProcessFrame(state.buffer);
```

This should solve the problem, assuming that is the only problem in your code.

EDIT:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/unity3d-c-sharp-plugin-to-act-as-a-socket-server/36526634#36526634) a complete TCP server code for Unity. Port the code to UDP and that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Could you point me to a correct way of using `Thread` to dealing with socket connection in Unity? many thanks :)

Comment: @ss1271 Before I do that, did this solve your problem?

Comment: hmm actually it is still stalling... but your suggestion is the correct practice so I followed.

Comment: @ss1271 There is likely other problems with your code. Anyways, here a complete TCP server code for Unity. Port the code to UDP and that should work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/unity3d-c-sharp-plugin-to-act-as-a-socket-server/36526634#36526634

Comment: yes. with your help I managed to get the socket connection part work. thanks. I'll update with more details later this day.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Could you explain a little bit more why the `Async` not work well? thanks

Comment: @ss1271 This is Unity that is using old mono. If you look at that link I posted in the answer, you will see the OP had a C# code that worked in Visual Studio in Microsoft net but failed to work in Unity. Just because it works in .NET does not mean it will work in Unity mono. Unity mono is years behind and needs many of their API to be updated with bug fixes. Until that is done, some things just won't work. All these problem will be solved when Unity updates to .NET 6 which is at the end of the year or early 2017.

Comment: FYI If you have the [Unity plugin for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx) you can tell Visual Studio to target the specialized version of Mono that Unity uses in the drop-down for your framework selection in the project properties. That way stuff that is not available for you to use in .NET won't show up in intellisense..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain These stuff are available and 100 percent supposed to be supported/working in Unity. The problem is that they are old and full of bug and needs to be updated. Mono fixed some of these bugs long time ago but I heard there is a licence problem without mono and Unity and that's why Unity cannot modify/fix those problems in mono without shelling out $$$.  Because of this, Unity partnered with Microsoft and joined the .NET foundation last month in order to update the C# API to .NET 6 which removes all the bugs. The only thing they have been able to modify was their own API.

Comment: @Programmer I see, thanks again for your advice and help